# Shouldn't such wide a question be systematically blacklisted?

Tags: discussion

A subject as "network problems" seems to be much too wide to contain the beginning of an analysis.
In a practical case:
[network problems](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18695/13986)
the problem presented shows in fact not the least beginning of real engineering level analysis.

Shouldn't there be a short black list of *obviously too wide titles*?
Something in line with the [Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/13986) of Mike Pennington.

I would start with:

- Internet not working
- *anything* not working
- Network problem
- *anything* problem

Comment: Automated title word filters are [hard to do correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so)

Comment: :) . But I wasn't thinking of any automated filtering embedded within SE. I know it will just shift the problem to pr0blem, prºblem, prøblem, prΩblem….

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree that this is an example of a terrible subject, but a subject does not make up the entire post, nor should a post be closed purely on the subject. Sometimes people get a bit overwhelmed or don't have a better way of framing the problem even in their own minds for a brief one line summary.

Keep in mind that SE's concept about moderation is that the communities are largely self-moderated. This means that there are tools you can use to address the problem as part of the community to make things better.

Community members have the ability to at least suggest edits (which if approved earns you reputation) to questions or answers that they feel need improving.  If you feel the subject isn't representative or accurate, please edit to improve as long as you don't change the intent of the original poster.

Alternatively, if you have the reputation to comment anywhere, you could suggest the OP do it themselves.

You can even go further ff you feel there are flaws with post by casting a down vote (again if you have the reputation). If it is then edited, your vote will unlock so you can remove it if you choose (or up vote if you feel it should be).