# Why is this question on hold?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

[This question got put on hold](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49889/remember-me-like-service-approach-to-google-starbucks-wifi?noredirect=1#comment84653_49889), but it seems to fall perfectly within the boundaries of what the forum is for.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Your question has several problems.

First, it is about a problem on a network that you do not directly control. You must contact the network administrators for help.

In your comment, you ask:

> Where in the description does it say that I have to control the
>   network?

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> **and meets the following requirements**
>
> - under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to
>     answer your question);
> - hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class
>     devices);

Even in your question, you say:

> They have asked me to call them regarding this.

That is exactly what you need to do.

You also ask:

> Does anyone have any tips to for them with respect to how this should
>   be engineered.

The answer to that question is, "No." We do not have any information about how the network is engineered, and we cannot speculate or guess, which is off-topic for Network Engineering. Questions that are too broad or solicit primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic. Neither can you give us the information necessary to troubleshoot a network that you do not directly control.

Your example:

> For example using a browser cookie or something instead of relying on
>   email and mac address?

This is also off-topic as protocols above OSI Layer 4.

---

You should look at the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499). I seriously doubt that you could provide the information necessary to even begin to help you.

Frankly, I do not see any way for you to salvage this question.