# Are any OSI layer4 network protocols on-topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, asking-questions

Quite often we seen comments like "protocols above Layer4 in the OSI model are **off-topic**": <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

[image: DHCP Off-topic]

Question: *Are there any OSI layer4 (or above) network protocol questions which are **on-topic**?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is On-Topic

> Are there any OSI layer4 (or above) network protocol questions which are 
>   on-topic?

Yes, this is even hinted at in the help center:

[image: design of protocols used to operate a network]

If the question is about the design, theory or even simply *using* features of protocols used to operate a network, then the question should be on-topic.  Protocols used to operate a network include (but are not limited to): ARP, RIP, OSPF, BGP, ISIS, SNMP, DHCP, RADIUS, TACACS+, NTP, YANG, NETCONF and DNS.  Some of the aforementioned protocols are certainly above OSI Layer4

## Potentially confusing guidance

What's confusing is that there is some conflicting guidance on this subject in the help center:

[image: Questions above OSI Layer4 off-topic]

Using this logic one could potentially argue that questions about the BGP protocol itself are off-topic; the BGP protocol sits squarely above TCP (i.e. above OSI Layer4) in the protocol stack.  However, that was [*not what we intended when we wrote the help center*](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/228/775).

## Why is this so confusing?

We are part of the Stack Exchange network.  There's this tiny site in the Stack Exchange network called [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where people often ask questions about code for network applications; as part of the Stack Exchange network, we get a significant amount of drive-by traffic from StackOverflow coders.  If we did not draw a hard line about protocols being supported, we could wind up fielding an endless march of questions about why someone's application broke over the network (or even the design / operation of their own custom network protocol).

Nevertheless, this distinction should *never* be used as a reason to close a question about the operation of someone's network, as long as they're using a *supported network infrastructure protocol* (i.e., it's not a network infrastructure protocol they made up on their own).

## People use http to manage firewalls; does this mean http qualifies as a network infrastructure protocol?

http is not a network infrastructure protocol in any significant way; it's primary use is for people to write portable GUIs for their applications.  The fact that we happen to use http to manage a firewall is simply because we need transport for a remote GUI / restful API.

## What can we do to improve this situation?

I believe we should modify the help center to be more explicit about the supported protocols *above OSI Layer4*.