# I disagree with my question being put on hold for being off-topic

Tags: support, off-topic, moderators

I don't see how my question is off-topic:

[Symmetric NAT traversal in 4G LTE networks](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63216/symmetric-nat-traversal-in-4g-lte-networks?noredirect=1#comment111757_63216)

I get that I made *some* murky statement, especially something like "forcing the ISPs to abandon IPv4 in favour of IPv6 in order to make NAT go down in the annals of history" and if that's the reason for putting it on hold, let me know and I'll go and remove those phrases.

However, I don't agree with the question being generally off-topic.

You and the community state that a question is on-topic if the following requirements are met. I think my question clearly meets at least partly or fully the following requirements:

1. it's about

   - servers operating as a router/switch/firewall;
   - design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc);
   - production troubleshooting or problem resolution;
   - implementing and enforcing network security or policies;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the one caveat: "*under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to answer your question)*." Also, the different LTE carriers do things differently, so there really isn't a one-size-fits-all answer.

There are also other reasons, such as CGNAT is for personal networks, not business networks. Also, consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic.

You have not given us any real network information, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance.

---

> servers operating as a router/switch/firewall;

I do not see that anywhere in your question, and we would need the manufacturer, model, and software in order to determine if the router/switch/firewall manufacturer offers optional, paid support (another caveat).

> design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP,
>   routing protocols, STP, etc);

You have not asked a question about any protocols.

> production troubleshooting or problem resolution;

Again, you have not described your network to any extent to be able to troubleshoot *your* network.

> implementing and enforcing network security or policies;

There is nothing in the question about network security or policies. If anything, you are attempting to bypass ISP policies, which is listed under Off-Topic: "*bypassing network security or policies*."

Comment: Do you think there's another forum where I may put my question then?

Comment: `You have not asked a question about any protocols.` NAT traversal, telephony tag and P2P - doesn't that imply STUN, TURN and ICE?

Comment: NAT is not a protocol, it is a method (kludge) of changing the addressing in a protocol, and it can cause you to need to use other kludges, some of which you have mentioned. It breaks protocols, but it is not a protocol. There are also several forms of NAT, some of which have been deprecated or are experimental.

Comment: It know NAT is not a protocol. But STUN is, right?

Comment: No, it is not. It is a method using an external server, and servers are off-topic.

Comment: I find that strange though that such questions are invalid on forums that are called "networking". Do you think there's another forum where I should put my question then?

Comment: This site is Network _Engineering_, and it deals with professionally managed networks in a business environment, not the hosts or servers that use the network. That is covered on other sites, such as [sf] for a business network, or [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Alright. Would you mind moving my question (if possible with the answer) over to SuperUser then? Thanks

Comment: I have asked a moderator on [su] if he would accept the question there, but he said, no, they would close it as too broad. They would want a lot more detail before it would be acceptable there. "_Needs a lot more details for us, and that in turn needs massive changes_"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll see if I edit my question. Should I flag it as "needing moderator intervention" or rather comment below or tag you here when I feel like it's suitable for SuperUser/ready to move?

Comment: You should simply ask it there. Start by copying everything you have now (Edit, Copy-All), then paste it into a question there and edit it before posting.