# Question about debugging an ipsec VPN connection - off topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I have the following situation: for an ipsec VPN endpoint, I am trying to troubleshoot failing connection and use vpnc tool.

Is a question like this going into more detail of the output offtopic?

Comment: We would need details, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance. Also, remember that home networking, consumer-grade devices, and host/server configurations are all off-topic here.