# router switch functionality/configuration - deemed off topic and closed - I disagree

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Configuring strict port isolation in home network](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69752/configuring-strict-port-isolation-in-home-network)

I am a non networking engineer
looking for functionality advice VPN/VLAN/IPSEC etc

Home is even in title, and with more people working remote - security in a home environment will exceed - "is it plugged in, turned on, and do you know the password, ok then call the vendor"

I have very specific needs, it is an all wired - cat 7 network - and need routing/switching advice for functionality/feasibility as we have a strict need for security.

If it's truly off topic I will yield - but do not consider it so - especially with the linked similar question posted and answered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that the depth of knowledge of the folks you're asking is generally around enterprise networking gear.  Asking questions about specific features of consumer-grade gear (i.e. Linksys, Netgear, Belkin) is roughly like going to a board for folks who maintain diesel engines on gigantic mining equipment and asking for advice on the funny noise your Honda Civic makes.  Yes, both machines have pistons and wheels and there's some amount of common theory but the folks over at the Honda board (or Super User, in this case) are going to be a lot more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that "*NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about **professionally managed networks** in a business environment.*" The community expects a certain level of expertise, and much more information, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, etc. that you have not even explained. (See the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance on what you should include in a question).

The community here has decided that home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic. Your question would just sit here with no activity because the community is not interested in those types of questions. You can refer to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page for what is on- or off-topic.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) explicitly allows such questions, and you can get an answer to your question there instead of letting your question languish on NE with no answer.

Comment: see - https://superuser.com/questions/1581427/networking-router-switch-capabilities-and-configuration-for-vlan-subnet-securi