# Change Title of the community?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am new to the network engineering community. Today I have done a very well formatted [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70913/routing-2-subnets) and I realized that the community is not related to consumer grade networking products and not even about home networking or a kind of *networking for dummies* but only for *enterprise-grade networking*. As such, simple networking questions like the one I did are not appropriate for the site. Other links with extra info about it:

[Has the community changed its mind about consumer-grade hardware?](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/567/has-the-community-changed-its-mind-about-consumer-grade-hardware)

and a closed question that does not involve *managed networks in a business environment*:

[router switch functionality/configuration - deemed off topic and closed - I disagree](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/router-switch-functionality-configuration-deemed-off-topic-and-closed-i-disa)

Perhaps the community should consider switching a name from *Network Engineering* to something that better represents its purpose? *Network Engineering* is quite generic as a term. Maybe the community should be named something like *Network Engineering for the Enterprise* or *Business environment networking* or something like else?

Comment: and also, remove the engineering part of it.

Comment: Since research is not allowed I would agree with @kaiya

Comment: "*something like Network Engineering for the Enterprise or Business environment networking*", except there is already [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) for business environment. (That's yet another site with a wonderful intuitively obvious name. And of course there's "Ask Different", whose useless name doesn't even match its URL.)

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing 'questions about consumer grade devices and home networking' with 'requests for product recommendations' in your examples. The latter is off topic for any network, consumer or professional.

Other than that, 'network engineering' *is* a term commonly used for professional networking, not for home networking. There's a clear [help text](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explaining which subjects are on topic here, which people can (and should) check before posting here.

Lastly, StackOverflow staff has repeatedly indicated (in general, not specifically for this site) that renaming a site is out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The site name is not "*Networking*". The "*Engineering*" in the name implies it is for professionals. There is no real engineering in home networking.

There are several SE sites for professionals, such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) where the names really do not imply professional, and that is why SE has a [Tour](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour), a [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), etc. pages for every SE site, and you are expected to familiarize yourself with the provided information before posting on a site.