# Let's allow network automation questions, such as ansible, Python used to administer routers, etc

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I was sad to see a [Python question about network automation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76305/network-automation-using-python) closed today, but programming questions are always swiftly dealt with.  I think this should change to increase good traffic within the NE.SX community.

The current [on-topic rules](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) include the following (excerpts):

- **On-topic** if your question is about **tools used by network professionals;**
- **Off-Topic** if your question is about: installation, configuration, or use of **applications not generally considered to be tools used by network professionals**;

To me, this suggests network automation questions should already be welcome; but perhaps not the most detailed programming questions.  With the current rules, a question about using ansible to admin a Cisco device ought be on-topic; but a question about writing a bespoke Python script to admin the same Cisco belongs elsewhere, e.g. on Stack Overflow.

I think this should change.  Our profession, Network Engineering, is racing toward a future where automation tools will be an unavoidable part of many network engineers' day-to-day responsibilities.  If you want a senior network engineering job today, you had better have at least some experience with ansible, puppet, SaltStack, or proprietary automation tools, or you might have a tough time finding a position!

By welcoming questions about network automation tools I think we'll draw more of the kind of traffic this community can thrive on.

By accepting some software development questions when they are specifically and narrowly focused on managing networks / network devices, I think we'll attract the same type of good-quality questions which in Super User or Server Fault might involve bash or Python scripting to achieve the ends sought by many users of their communities.

I would like to learn the process for proposing an addition to the on-topic rules:

- **On-topic** if your question is about a vendor-supported or mainstream open source network automation tool (such as ansible), and the question is focused on managing professionally-supported network devices
- **On-topic** if your question is about programming and narrowly focused on managing professionally-supported network devices (e.g. a Python script to access a router API and update an interface configuration)

I further suggest that when programming questions arrive which are not so narrowly focused, we should attempt to move those to Stack Overflow instead of let them die on our vine and frustrate users.

Comment: Hello Jeff... I think you're correct to say "Our profession, Network Engineering, is racing toward a future where automation tools will be an unavoidable part of many network engineers' day-to-day responsibilities".  Another "race" - companies are moving their physical datacenters to AWS, Google-cloud and Azure.  To deal with those dynamics, it helps to know [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/ "Terraform")

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I'd be in favor of opening up networking automation type questions to this community. I like the definitions you suggested.

Comment: I would agree on this too.

Answer (score 2):

## Background

When we started, [NE.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) was actively identifying itself as a community and we got some bleed-over questions from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)... there was also some confusion among [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) users / mods about what [NE.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) would cover.

Normally it would happen when someone would write some code to do something that involved a detailed network function (maybe involving heavy protocol-theory), and then there would be a knee-jerk reaction from some vocal [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) users to close the question and suggest they send it here.  Since we originally did not support anything related to code, the question would get closed and maybe there would be an argument about it (burning more mod time).

We initially had so much moderation workload that we were afraid to allow anything resembling programming / automation just so we would not get into some endless meta discussions about whether the question was or was not on-topic.

We don't have that kind of heavy site traffic / mod load now.  *I am in favor of adding automation questions*; see below for details.

## On / Off-Topic Automation Questions

I think this is a decent start at solving the on / off-topic discussion for network automation:

- Good automation question: `How do I use Salt-stack to do foo?` (where the question about doing foo is a [good question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/775) and scoped to the point that we're not doing most of their job for them)
- Maybe off-topic automation question: `Should I use Ansible or Terraform to do foo?` (depending on whether both Terraform and Ansible are both good at foo)
- Probably off-topic automation question: `Is SQL, YAML or JSON better for storing a network inventory?` (primarily opinion-based)
- Definitely off-topic automation question (summarizing): `Please write this automation code for me - from scratch`